# explode в цикле php

Tags: php, html, sql

Есть например в базе 10 строк со столбцами например img и есть цикл php.

Никак не могу понять как сделать.
например в цикле вывожу img все 10 строк, будет что-то типа этого : 1.jpg2.jpg3.jpg4.jpg и тд.

как одной переменной это всё вывести за пределы цикла? чтобы было так же 1.jpg2.jpg3.jpg4.jpg

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table");
while ($row = $sql ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  
    echo $row['img']; // например 4 строки с img будет выглядеть так:1.jpg2.jpg3.jpg4.jpg  
}

// мы уже за пределами цикла и сюда нужно вывести $row['img']
```

Comment: покажите код и желаемы результат

Comment: в чём проблема выводить в цикле?

Comment: добавил код и что должно получиться

Comment: после цикла echo $row['img'] выведет последнее значение. А так - собирайте в цикле в массив

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нужно сделать видимыми последние например 5 элментов (напрмер картинок), а других переменных больше. LIMIT в моем случае не подходить. Думал разбить эксплодом картинки, и вывести сколько мне нужно, но крутил и так и сяк и ничего не вышло.

Comment: для условия есть оператор `if` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   Он в любом случае понадобится........ а вообще у БД есть ключевое слово LIMIT  и  ORDER BY

Comment: @splash58 что-то буду колхозить. Может втупую сессию сделать из цикла)))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Как if вывести последние id если они будут добавляться/удаляться и тд. Мне нужно чтобы выводилось всё, но для определенных переменных (в примере у нас img) сделать ограничение

Comment: `ЕСЛИ (счётчик > длинаМассива - 5) Вывести`

Comment: Так в итоге что-то и не ясно что нужно))  и чем не устраивает то, что есть.....онн же выполняет ту функцию, что и требуется, разве нет?................ А в целом, splash58 написал - что, если нужно, можно складывать просто всё в массив, а потом (**в другом цикле**) с этой переменной выводить что-то

Comment: Вот зачем получать ВСЁ, а потом заниматься выбором одного поля и перебора в цикле с объединением в одно значение. когда можно сразу запросить одно объединённое значение этого самого поля?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вариант 1 по мере перебора цикла добавляем значение в переменную $fullrow таким образом все названия изображений в одной переменной

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table");
while ($row = $sql ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  
    $fullrow .= $row['img'];
}
// мы уже за пределами цикла и сюда мы можем вывести $fullrow
echo $fullrow;
```

вариант 2 по мере перебора цикла добавляем значение в специально созданный массив $fullrowarray который сохранит все img за пределами цикла;

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table");
while ($row = $sql ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  
    $fullrowarray[] = $row['img']; 
}

// мы уже за пределами цикла и мы можем использовать массив $fullrowarray  
// например вывести его содержимое на экран
print_r( $fullrowarray );
```

Answer (score 0):

Идеологически - так:

```sql
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(img) AS img FROM table");
$row = $sql ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['img'];
```

Вывод: `1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg`

Если не нравится разделитель-запятая, измени запрос.

PS. В PHP не смыслю ни хрена - так что с синтаксисом могу и наврать. Но на суть это не влияет.

Comment: Пускай лучше человек для начала научится работать с циклами и массивами в PHP, т.к. речь идёт изначально про него, а не про SQL.

Comment: @xRef Если он пишет код в учебных целях - да, конечно. Хотя невредно запомнить, что это неправильный подход. Но если это код, который пойдёт в проду, то делать через задницу категорически не стОит...

Answer (score 0):

А вот так не канает?

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table");
$rowsList_ARR   =   $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($rowsList_ARR);
```

Если нужно как-то по-красивому, каким-то списком, то можно так :

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table");
$rowsList_ARR   =   $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rowsCount_INT  =   $sql->rowCount();

$result_TEXT    =   '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $rowsCount_INT; $i++) {
    
    if ($i > 0) { $result_TEXT  .=  ', '; }
    $result_TEXT    .=  $rowsList_ARR[$i];
    
}

echo $result_TEXT;
```